# How to make iPhone track itself on a map?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, location

For Example, I travel from San Diego to La, I want the iPhone to track how long it was from San Diego to La and tell me the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app is in the background it could still receive location info when there is a significan location change such as new cell tower. Your app could monitor the significan location changes as well as regular gps when it's available and calculate the time difference.

Check out Starting the Significant-Change Location Service

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10

Also this is a good tutorial for using significan time change notifications:
http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2011/07/ios-background-location/

For basic MapKit usage check out [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreLocation to track the phone with GPS, storing the position every so often (either do it every X minutes, or every X miles/degrees-latitude-longitude.

The [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) class is what you want, most likely. You give it a delegate that receives events, and start it polling. To conserve battery, you don't necessarily want it to be polling continuously, but you can set it up to automatically turn off and then back on again in a little while.

Displaying it on a map is slightly more complicated, but still quite easy to do. If you need Geocoding, you'll probably need to use the Google Maps API.